Showing that z is a root of $X^n -1$ iff z is an element of the set of generators of dth roots of unity for some $d\mid n.$
I would like to show that $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is the root of $X^n -1$ if and only if $z \in \mu^*_d$ for a certain $d \in \mathbb{N}$ which divides n where $\mu^*_d$ is the set of generators of the group of dth roots of unity.
My attempt for the first part of the exercise is:
(=>) Suppose $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $X^n -1$
$z^n =1$ where $n=qd$ for $q \in \mathbb{N}$
Therefore $z^{qd} =1$
z is a root of unity so:
$z^n=(\exp(\frac{2 k \pi i}{n}))^{n}=\exp(\frac{2 k \pi i}{n})^{qd}$
From here I want to argue that this will somehow show that z should be an element of $\mu^*_d$ but I can't see the missing argument.
Am I on the right path and if so what am I missing?

Your title is wrong - $z$ doesn't have to be a :generator," it just has to be an $n$th root of unity, practically by definition. Or $z$ has to be a power of a generator of the group of $n$th roots of unity.

Unless there was a misunderstanding on my part, this was exactly how the question was asked. I admit that I was also confused.

Is there a typo?  I would think it should be $\mu_d^*$ is the set of generators of the group of $d$th roots of unity (instead of $n$th roots of unity).

Yes, it was supposed to be the dth root.

You're off a little,  but playing with some of the tools.
Suppose $z^n=1$ and $z$ is not a primitive $n$th root of unity.
Then $z=e^{2\pi ik/n},$ where $(k,n)\gt1.$
But then $z$ is a primitive $n/(n,k)$-th root of unity.   See here.
The converse is rather trivial.

Thanks a lot! It’s much more clear now
